# Jackson to convert a json into a map of String and a list

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson, objectmapper

I have a json like below

```
{
  "department": [
    {
      "status": "active",
      "count": "100"
    },
    {
      "status": "active",
      "count": "300"
    }
  ],
  "finance": [
    {
      "status": "inactive",
      "count": "500"
    },
    {
      "status": "active",
      "count": "450"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Object is like below

```
class CurrentInfo
{
private String status;
private int count;
//getters and setters
}
```

I wanted to convert this JSON to a `Map<String,List<CurrentInfo>>`. I can convert the individual nodes using the below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CurrentInfo currentinfo = mapper.readValue(jsonString, CurrentInfo.class);
```

Is there a way I can convert the previously mentioned JSON directly into a `Map<String,List<CurrentInfo>>`

Comment: what would be `key` of your map? `department` , `finance` and .. ?

Comment: @user404 Yes. you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, and according to JSON above `count` is `String` type not `int`

```
class CurrentInfo {
    private String status;
    private String count;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The use `TypeReference` to convert json string to java object

```
Map<String, List<CurrentInfo>> currentInfo = mapper.readValue(
        jsonString,
        new TypeReference<Map<String, List<CurrentInfo>>>() {});
```